# E: Package 'python' has no installation candidate

Tags: python

I have been experimenting with some hacking tools (like hydro) recently and I came across a tool called Responder. It basically opens an SMB server that grabs the NetNTLMv for the administrative user from a server/client (BTW I am still a beginner so please go easy on me if I am wrong). I tried to run the script by typing `./Responder.py -I tun0` but it said `/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory`. I understood that python was not installed so I ran `sudo apt install python` but instead of it telling me that the installation was complete, it told me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  2to3 python2-minimal:i386 python2:i386 python2-minimal python2 dh-python
  python-is-python3

E: Package 'python' has no installation candidate
```

The output remained the same even after running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and after rebooting.

I remember python working before the last update so I'm not really sure what to do.

Version: Ubuntu 22.04 amd64

(Note: I tapped into the Responder.py code and I saw that in the shebang line, it specifically required python 1, so python 2 and 3 aren't supposed to work...I tried it anyways and as I guessed, it did not work.)

Comment: @guiverc okay...let me add it real quick. Also btw I tapped into the code and found that Responder is made for python1, and I tried it with python 2 and python 3...both didn't work. So I really need a way to install python1.

Comment: @guiverc sorry again...its amd64

Answer (score 5):

All recent Ubuntu installations use `python3` only.

To run programs that point to `python`, install the package `python-is-python3`:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Or manually create a symlink to `python3` (which basically is what the above package does):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I thought this would work but I tapped into the code and found that Responder is made for python1, and I tried it with python 2 and python 3...both didn't work. So I really need a way to install python1.

Comment: Well good luck - or maybe you should use software designed for today and not a 25-year old version of Python?

Comment: I have tried doing that..but none of them work...I found one called Responder3 which was made for Python3...But that didn't work...

Comment: Well it hasn't been [updated for 4-5 years](https://github.com/skelsec/Responder3). But should serve as a good starting point to develop the app further, if you should wish to do so..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Python 2 on Ubuntu 22.04, the recipe is:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python2

$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.18
```

But, as noted, Python 2.7 is end-of-life (as of 2020-01-01), and deprecated in recent Ubuntu releases.

---

<sup>If you **really** need Python 1.x ... you will need to download the source code for 1.6.1 and build it for yourself.  That would be kind of crazy ... since 1.6.1 was officially end-of-life in 2000.</sup>